# How to manually decode an an array in swift 4 Codable?

Tags: swift, codable

Here is my code. But I do not know what to set the value to. It has to be done manually because the real structure is slightly more complex than this example.

Any help please?

```
struct Something: Decodable {
   value: [Int]

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKeys {
      case value
   }

   init (from decoder :Decoder) {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      value = ??? // < --- what do i put here?
   }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile due to a few mistakes / typos.

To decode an array of `Int` write

```
struct Something: Decodable {
    var value: [Int]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case value
    }

    init (from decoder :Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        value = try container.decode([Int].self, forKey: .value)
    }
}
```

---

But if the sample code in the question represents the entire struct it can be reduced to

```
struct Something: Decodable {
    let value: [Int]
}
```

because the initializer and the `CodingKeys` can be inferred.

Comment: thanks.. i was trying `[Int.self]` . Didn't realize the `.self` had to be on the outside

Comment: I belive you can also just specify `Array.self` and `Array<Int>.self` (e.g. `[Int].self`) will be inferred from `value`’s declared type.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for Joshua Nozzi's hint. Here's how I implement to decode an array of Int:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let intArray = try? decoder.decode([Int].self, from: data)
```

without decoding manually.

Answer (score 6):

### **Swift 5.1**

In my case, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49149416/5376525) was very helpful

I had a **JSON** in format: **`"[ "5243.1659 EOS" ]"`**

So, you can decode data without keys

```
struct Model: Decodable {
    let values: [Int]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        let values = try container.decode([Int].self)
        self.values = values
    }
}
```

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let result = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it generic:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let intArray:[Int] = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
```