# Decode an Array of an custom struct in Swift out of the UserDefaults

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsuserdefaults

I want to encode an Array of my own struct, which I want to save in UserDefaults, and then read It out (after decoding it). I know how to code the first part (following), that means how to encode an array and save it in Userdefaults.

```
struct mystruct: Codable {
var int: Int
var string: String
}

var array = [mystruct(int: 2, string: "Example"), mystruct(int: 5, string: "Other Example")]

var encodedArray = try JSONEncoder().encode(array)

UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedArray, forKey: "array")
```

I also know how to get the data back from the Userdefaults:

```
var newArray = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "array")
```

But I don't know how to decode an whole array...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually decode an an array in swift 4 Codable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857326/how-to-manually-decode-an-an-array-in-swift-4-codable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass your custom structure array type `[MyStruct].self` to the `JSONDecoder`:

---

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
    let int: Int
    let string: String
}
```

---

```
let myStructures: [MyStruct] = [.init(int: 2, string: "Example"),
                         .init(int: 5, string: "Other Example")]
```

---

```
do {
    let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(myStructures)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "array")
    if let decodedData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "array") {
        let decodedArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyStruct].self, from: decodedData)
        print(decodedArray)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

This will print:

> [MyStruct(int: 2, string: "Example"), MyStruct(int: 5, string: "Other Example")]